# how to run LightWeight parallel java JAR file in linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar, lightweight-processes

i need to run a program called Node that will run the the same program with different parameters. This has to be done in school linux machine so it does not have enough memory space. So the professor said to use this command to run it: and called it Lightweight Java

```
   java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:ConcGCThreads=1 -Xmx5m -Xms5m -Xss5m HelloWorld
```

but how would this command work for .jar file? this is a shell script for the run without the lightweight command.

```
   alias node="java -cp node.jar Node"
   node 0 100 5 "MSG" 20 1 2 &
   node 1 100 1 0 2 &
   node 2 100 2 0 1 3 4 &
   node 3 100 3 2 4 &
   node 4 100 4 2 3 5 &
   node 5 100 5 4 &
```

how can i turn this to lightweight?

Comment: Ask your professor.

Comment: @Kayaman do you know how to convert my jar file to a normal java file so i can run that command on it?

Comment: You could add the parameters to the `alias` part in the shell script.

Comment: @Kayaman  alias part you mean instead of the word alias i put all those? could you clarify exactly by writing it?

Comment: No, add those parameters to the java call inside the alias.